# Why does my root node change when I insert item in BST?

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to construct a BST from data in a csv file. My code works just fine when I tested it with hardcoded the input, but when I read from the csv file, the root node keep changing to the newly added node for some reason,so I assume there is nothing wrong with my addNode() function but something wrong with my main. What is wrong with my code? Please help.

```
int main()
{

    char buff[512];
    Node* root = makeNode("CC","ID 100985");
    FILE* fp= fopen("athlete_test.csv","r");
    int i = 0;
    while(fgets(buff, 512, (FILE*)fp)>0){
        Data* data = malloc(sizeof(Data));
        data->ID = strtok(buff,",");
        char* Name = strtok(NULL,",");
        data->Sex = strtok(NULL,",");
        data->Age = strtok(NULL,",");
        data->Height = strtok(NULL,",");
        data->Weight = strtok(NULL,",");
        data->Team = strtok(NULL,",");
        data->NOC = strtok(NULL,",");
        data->Games = strtok(NULL,",");
        data->Year = strtok(NULL,",");
        data->Season = strtok(NULL,",");
        data->City = strtok(NULL,",");
        data->Sport = strtok(NULL,",");
        data->Event = strtok(NULL,",");
        data->Medal = strtok(NULL,",");;
        if (i==0)
        {
            root = makeNode(Name,data);
            i++;
            printNode(root);
        }else
        {
           addNode(root,Name,data);
           printNode(root);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

Node* makeNode(char* key,Data* data)
{

    Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->key = key;
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->leftNode = NULL;
    newNode->rightNode = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

Node* addNode(Node* root,char* key,Data* data)
{

    Node* newNode = makeNode(key,data);

    Node* currentNode = root;
    while(currentNode != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(currentNode->key,newNode->key)>=0)
        {
            if(currentNode->leftNode == NULL)
            {
                currentNode->leftNode = newNode;
                break;
            }
            currentNode = currentNode->leftNode;
        }
        else
        {
            if(currentNode->rightNode == NULL)
            {
                currentNode->rightNode = newNode;
                break;
            }
            currentNode = currentNode->rightNode;
        }
    }
    currentNode = newNode;
    return newNode;

}
```

Theoretically whenever I print root it will be the same, but in reality my result is every single node I added in order.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: And please don't post images of code (or text in general). Copy-paste it into the question instead.

Comment: You should really read `strtok()`'s manual. Also, since `root` is a pointer you could instead check `if (root == NULL) ... create_root();` instead of using such a confusing `i` variable.

Comment: Each line read from file overwrites the previous line and so the pointers obtained from `strtok` become useless.

Comment: Another aside: `fgets(. . .) > 0` should be `fgets(. . .) != NULL`

Comment: What should I do to resolve the overwriting issue?Thank you

Comment: By making copies of each data item, such as with `strdup` although it is not a standard function.

Comment: @CocoKneer please read the documentation of [`man strtok(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok_r.3.html) throughly. That way you would understand why data is overwritten. If you don't understand after reading it, then I suggest studying pointers again. I would also suggest a `parse_line_and_set_node_data()` function to help you write more readable code. Inside the loop there should only be code related to the BST and nothing more.

Comment: We need the definition of `Node` and `Data`. Without it we cannot help you.

Comment: You need to read about `strtok`. I always say "_If nothing helps, read the manual!_"

Comment: Once you battle through why your nodes point to the same things, you'll hit the road block where `addNode` is broken (and believe me; it's broken; it doesn't hang new nodes in the tree; rather it's a memory leak machine that does nothing to the provided tree). A *debugger* will be monumental in discovering why.

Comment: Read [How To Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: to help us assist you, please post a [mcve]  Only posting parts of the code leaves us guessing about the missing parts

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by various other experts, there are multiple issues with your code snippet. I'll list down a few:

1. Incorrect usage of `strtok`: strtok returns a *pointer* to the beginning of the discovered token and at the same time also *modifies* the input char array which in your case is `buff`. I've prepared a small code snippet which will help you to better understand the behaviour of the function, https://ideone.com/6NCcrR. Consider using `strcpy` to create a copy of the returned string instead of assigning it directly.
2. Prefer `fgets(...) != NULL` over `fgets(...) > 0`, you can understand more about the return value of `fgets` from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm).
3. Your logic for the function `addNode` is incorrect. Though it's not the most neatest way to proceed, but changing the `break;` in your function to `return newNode;` should help a bit. This will avoid the line `currentNode = newNode;` to be executed every time the function is called which is the problem in your case.

Please feel free to cross-question me or correct me if I'm wrong.